# Scraping a table within a website - how to find the table from elements?

Tags: r, html-parsing

Looking to scrape a table from this site -

https://dr16.sdss.org/optical/spectrum/search?id=285009 [based on https://labrtorian.com/2017/08/14/parse-an-online-table-into-an-r-dataframe-westgards-biological-variation-database/

and

[https://www.r-bloggers.com/2015/01/using-rvest-to-scrape-an-html-table/]](https://www.r-bloggers.com/2015/01/using-rvest-to-scrape-an-html-table/%5D).

All the data is numeric.

The following libraries were employed -

`library(httr)`
`library(rvest)`
`library(xlsx)`

`astro <- session("https://dr16.sdss.org/optical/spectrum/search?id=285009")`
`xpaths <- paste0("paste0('//*[@id="results"]/div[1]/div[2][', 1:1, ']")`

`spectable = data.frame(matrix(NA, 0, 10))`

#loop over the 1 html table

`for (j in 1:1){`

`subtable <- astro %>%`

```
`read_html() %>%`
`html_nodes(xpath =  xpaths[j] ) %>%`
`html_table(., fill = TRUE)`
```

`subtable <- subtable[[1]]`
`spectable <- rbind(spectable, subtable)`
}

`## Error in subtable[[1]] : subscript out of bounds`

`table.header <- c("Plate", "MJD" ,"FibreID", "specobj_id", "RA", "Dec", "z","zerr", "S/N", "class")`

`names(spectable) <- table.header`

There is only 1 table, the various fields are populated by the user completing certain fields. e.g say Plate = 400. There is an option to set the number of rows on the table - say 10.

I am unable to figure out how to define the table from within the webpage using xpaths, elements does not clearly show the table. The best I could come up with was

`xpaths <- paste0("//*[@id="results"]/div[1]/div[2][", 1:1, "]")`

which returned the error

`"unexpected symbol in ..."`

A second issue, presumably related to the first, is defining the row names. The script uses this

`row.names(spectable) <- 1:nrow(spectable)`

where nrow = number of rows in the table.

The returned error is

`Error in .rowNamesDF<-(x, value = value) : invalid 'row.names' length`

Would appreciate any enlightenment. Thank you.

Comment: Hi, could you take a read of [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251361/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks) which shows you how to format the code in your question - it makes it easier for others to read it. It's easiest to use the backticks `. Thanks.

Comment: Try to replace your `paste0`-statement with `paste0('//*[@id="results"]/div[1]/div[2][', 1:1, ']')`, since you are using `"` inside one argument.

Comment: you've not included any libraries. Could you include enough code to repro these issues please. I'm thinking perhaps you are using rvest and having problems because tables are dynamically added. Were you trying to complete with specific options selected?

Comment: Thx user438383 for showing how to present my case, appreciated.

Comment: Martin Gal - unfortunately your suggestion made no difference, thx anyway

Comment: QHarr - have provided additional info, per suggestion.  The table is populated, by the user.